Discord Slash Commands In Python Not Working
So I tried like every which way to use a slash command in the python environment. Even hybrid commands, in which the prefix version works but the slash command doesn't even appear. I have all the scopes correct, the guild id correct (for quicker syncing but I've also tried global), permissions are fine, all the intents are fine and so on. I've triple checked this stuff. At my current setup, I'm starting the bot from the main.py and then loading cogs.
This is my main.py:
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import datetime
import os

bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix=",",
    intents=discord.Intents.all(),
    status=discord.Status.dnd,
    activity=discord.Activity(
        type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="Ursf"
    ),
)

bot.remove_command("help")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    try:
        await bot.tree.sync()
        guild = discord.Object(id={guild_id_here})
        await bot.tree.sync(guild=guild)
        print(f"Slash commands synced to guild: {guild.id}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to sync commands: {e}")

    print("\n\n    bot is ready!")
    
    for fn in os.listdir("./cogs"):
        if fn.endswith(".py"):
            try:
                await bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{fn[:-3]}")
                print(f"\n    loaded extensions: {fn}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"    failed to load extension(s) {fn}: {e}")

bot.run("{token}")

and when i run this i get the print saying everything is synced and the cogs are loaded and so on. This is the cog code I'm trying to load:
class SipBot(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.hybrid_command(name="hello", description="Says hello")
    async def newhello(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("Hello from both prefix and slash")

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(SipBot(bot))

At my current stage I was testing the hybrid decorator but I'm aware there is more. And yes I have tested a multitude of them. I can successfully execute the ",hello" command and it work fine but the "/hello" slash command is no where to be found in any of my attempts. I've even kicked the bot and re-added it.
Just for a little more information, I'm using VS2022 and python version 3.11. the discord.py version is 2.4.0 and I do not have the discord package installed (incase of confliction).
Any suggestions? The command I'm trying to create has a multitude of arguments so I need to visually show the arguments (as a slash command can do) or just launch a modal from said slash command.


Make sure you have permission to use slash commands and the commands are authorized on the channel where you are testing;
Check if you are using the latest version of the Discord app;
Try restarting your Discord app to force update the slash commands in your Discord client.


for #1: yes the bot has proper permission via the developer portal and the server itself.
for #2: usually i am on the latest version of actual discord, but with that being said can "Vencord" be an issue? I didnt think that could be an issue since its a client thing.
for #3: I have tried this plenty of times with no change.

1 and 3. I'm not referring to your bot, but to your Discord account that's trying to use the commands;


I recommend that you test with the official application, as alternative versions of Discord may not yet support slash commands.


Do not sync on on_ready(), since it can load at random times, and since you're calling it every time you start your bot, it can cause ratelimiting issues. It would be better that you created a new command, like:
@bot.command("sync")
async def sync(ctx: discord.Context):
   
   await bot.tree.sync()

Also, the tree.sync() function only accepts a discord.Snowflake as its argument, so instead of using discord.Object, you can just enter in the id of the guild you want to sync it to. (Snowflakes are documented here: snowflakes)
